# A microphone and my Yamaha PRS E363

Tags: keyboard

I am a beginner and I need to by a microphone.  I want to make sure I make the right choice.
Can a microphone be connected to my Yamaha E363? 
Can I use a microphone connected thru my computer?
Is both methods possible?

Comment: Check out my video recording mike connected e 373 https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=cRhoZxgnAbE

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can connect a microphone to the Yamaha E363.

The E363 has an AUX-in that uses a mini-plug. To send a microphone through to the AUX-in you will need a microphone, a mixer or pre-amp, and a cable that fits the output of the mixer or pre-amp and has a mini connector on the other end.

The mixer or pre-amp can be a simple and/or inexpensive device, it just needs to convert the microphone level into Line Level. Some examples (not a recommendation, just examples of types of hardware) are:

[Rolls MP13 mini mixer](https://rolls.com/product/MP13)

[Bheringer pre-amp](https://www.behringer.com/Categories/Behringer/Signal-Processors/Microphone-Preamplifiers/MIC100/p/P0207)

There are many options available.

You can also send a microphone signal to the keyboard through a computer using the USB input. This will be more complicated, and would require a digital interface for the microphone to go into the computer with, and software on the computer to send the signal to the keyboard (DAW or Digital Audio Workstation software). An example of the hardware you might use to connect a microphone to the computer is:

[Scarlett 2i2](https://focusrite.com/usb-audio-interface/scarlett/scarlett-2i2)

As for the microphone, what kind you buy is dependant on what you want to use it for. A simple Dynamic Microphone should be enough if you are using it to sing along to what you are playing on the keyboard.  There are many tutorials on-line on getting started with microphones, and browsing the Microphone tag on this Stack Exchange may give you some useful information; https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microphones